# Linux Bash count and summarize by unique columns

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

I have a text file with lines like this (in Linux Bash):

```
A B C D
A B C J
E B C P
E F G N
E F G P
A B C Q
H F S L
G Y F Q
H F S L
```

I need to find the lines with unique values for the first 3 columns, print their count and then print summarized last column for each unique line, so the result is like this:

```
3 A B C D,J,Q
1 E B C P
2 E F G N,P
1 G Y F Q
2 H F S L
```

**What I have tried:**

```
cat FILE | sort -k1,3 | uniq -f3 -c | sort -k3,5nr
```

Is there maybe any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Are the unique groups always formed by adjacent lines?

Comment: Thanks for the question - not necessarily, lines doesn't need to be adjacent, I have edited now the original post.

Comment: I got to the point to have counts for the first three columns, but the last values are not grouped: $ cat FILE | sort -k1,3 | uniq -f3 -c | sort -k3,5nr

Comment: Modifying your requirements after you have received answers is dubious practice. Perhaps you should roll back your latest edit, accept one of the answers, and post a new question with your *actual* requirements as well as your code so far.

Comment: @Igor, please always add your efforts in you post only, comments are not made for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to do the following:

```
awk '{key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; a[key]=a[key]","$4; c[key]++}
     END{for(key in a) { print c[key],key,substr(a[key],2) }}' <file>
```

If you do not want any duplication, you can do

```
awk '{ key=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; c[key]++ }
     !gsub(","$4,","$4,a[key]) {a[key]=a[key]","$4; }
     END{for(key in a) { print c[key],key,substr(a[key],2) }} <file>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great answer! Is there any way to avoid printing duplication on the last column if values are the same? I have edited the question now. For example, fourth line in the result ideally should be "2 H F S L", with the script you sent it will be "2 H F S L,L" as the value from last column is the same.

Comment: Thanks - looks like the second script won't print the fourth column (only first three)?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.
This will give you output in same sequence as per Input_file's `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` occurrence only.

```
awk '
!a[$1,$2,$3]++{
  b[++count]=$1 FS $2 FS $3
}
{
  c[$1,$2,$3]=c[$1,$2,$3]?c[$1,$2,$3] "," $4:$0
  d[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print d[b[i]],c[b[i]]
  }
}
' SUBSEP=" "  Input_file
```

Comment: For clarityshould test for `($1,$2,$3) in c`, not `c[$1,$2,$3]` in the (unparenthesized!) ternary. Your code would be more concise if you add `{key = $1 FS $2 FS $3}` at the top and then used `key` everywhere you use `$1 FS $2 FS $3` or `$1,$2,$3` instead of repeating that same combination of fields over and over, and you can also get rid of `SUBSEP=" "` if you do that. Also - what is the point of `d[]` when you have `a[]`? Give your arrays and other variables meaningful names and youll be less likely to have redundant code (in this case youd have created 2 arrays named something like `cnt[]`)

Answer (score 0):

Another using GNU awk and 2d arrays for removing duplicates in `$4`:

```
$ awk '{
    i=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3                        # key to hash
    a[i][$4]                                  # store each $4 to separate element
    c[i]++                                    # count key references
}
END {
    for(i in a) {                             
        k=1                                   # comma counter for output
        printf "%s %s ",c[i],i                # output count and key
        for(j in a[i])                        # each a[]i[j] element
            printf "%s%s",((k++)==1?"":","),j # output commas and elements
        print ""                              # line-ending
    }
}' file
```

Output in default random order:

```
2 E F G N,P
3 A B C Q,D,J
1 G Y F Q
1 E B C P
2 H F S L
```

Since we are using GNU awk the order of output could be affected easily by setting `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`:

```
3 A B C D,J,Q
1 E B C P
2 E F G N,P
1 G Y F Q
2 H F S L
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize  [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html):

```
$ cat input
A B C D
A B C J
E B C P
E F G N
E F G P
A B C Q
H F S L
G Y F Q
H F S L
$ datamash -t' ' --sort groupby 1,2,3 unique 4 count 4 < input
A B C D,J,Q 3
E B C P 1
E F G N,P 2
G Y F Q 1
H F S L 2
```

This unfortunately outputs the count as the last column. If it is absolutely necessary for it to be the first column, you will have to reformat it:

```
$ datamash -t' ' --sort groupby 1,2,3 unique 4 count 4 < input | awk '{$0=$NF FS $0; NF--}1'
3 A B C D,J,Q
1 E B C P
2 E F G N,P
1 G Y F Q
2 H F S L
```